# docx.py inserts empty strings between each element on Windows

Tags: python, docx

docx.py works fine on linux (ubuntu) but inserts empty strings between each element on Windows.
Will be appreciate for any advices:

```
    Welcome to Python's docx module






    Make and edit docx in 200 lines of pure Python
```

Comment: Hey, what do you call an element ? What's your code area about ?

Comment: I mean each string (line)

Comment: Could you please give your code

Comment: It's what I get simply using stardart example-makedocument.py

Comment: Just found out the issue is only in OpenOffice. Looks fine in LibreOffice and WordViewer

Comment: Could you please send generated docx to see what's wrong.

Comment: but is it possible to upload file here?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8USnPru0OfQUF4WkI0RDF5TWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The issue is only in OpenOffice. Looks fine in LibreOffice and WordViewer